# How can I run PSExec command as the primary user

Tags: powershell, directory, remote-access, psexec

I'm trying to write a little script that will output the appdata directory of every domain-connected computer's primary user into a text file on my own laptop. As of right now, I have it working if I specify the username (e.g. C:\users\USERNAME\appdata), but it needs to be more generic so that it will run on every computer on the domain. This is what I have so far:

```
.\PsExec.exe \\* C:\cygwin64\bin\dir.exe "C:\users\USERNAME\AppData\" > \\PCNAME\C$\users\USERNAME\desktop\Chrome_Extensions.txt
```

I'd like to be able to specify the primary user across the domain, but using something like `%USERPROFILE%` instead of `C:\users\USERNAME\` obviously won't work. Does anyone know of a way I can accomplish this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can workout the workstations primary user without something like SCCM. And even SCCM will take a while to associate a machine to a user account.

It might be best to have your script run as a login script for the current logged on user. It isn't advisable to try send output back to you laptop as it might be powered off at times. Ideally is should go back to a shared folder on a server which all users have access to.

Also PowerShell is a better choice than psexec here.

```
If (Test-Path -Path "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions"){
    Get-ChildItem -Path "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions" | Out-File -FilePath "\\SERVER\SHARENAME\$ENV:COMPUTERNAME-Chrome_Extensions.txt"
    }
```